# SQL Server: Columns not shown

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I edited a table in designer. But when I write a query it does not show columns in the context menu. Can someone help me to understand why?

Comment: dont blame me, i voted to move to dba.se

Comment: I retract my off-topic vote and instead call Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349366/schema-changes-not-updating-in-intellisense-in-sql-2008-ssms ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just press ctrl+shift+r in ssms  query window

actually it rakes a while after adding the column and refreshed to ssms but by pressing ctrl+shift+r it will refresh the schema of the table.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server Management Studio caches data. You must refresh the cache once changes are made after the initial connection. You can use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to do this or through the context menu:

[image]

Comment: For additional IntelliSense troubleshooting help, [see this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/).